# ZMQ 1-n queued vs multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, zeromq

Im interested in the conceptual efficencies of 1-n vs multithreading in ZMQ.

let me start by giving a conseptual problem:

I have 20 clients and one server. (I'll use push and pull sockets for ease but im interested if the answer changes with rep, req, dealer, router  as well).

If the clients have push sockets and the server a pull, then all the messages come into the single pull on the server. ZMQ will fair queue the push messages to the server and the context can be given an initialisation argument for the number of threads to use.

But what is happening under the hood? is it polling the inputs or multithreading comunications between them. Would any performance benifits be gained from multithreading them yourself?

I can see three ways to make the system described above (20 clients one server).

1) use one pull socket on the server and pushes on each client.

2) use 20 pull sockets on the server, using zmq poll to select ones with activity. clients still each have a push socket.

3) use 20 pull socets on the server each within its own thread (e.g. 20 threads). Clients have the same 20 push sockets (1 each).

i understand that not using option 1 im loosing the dynamic nature of newly joined clients and option 2 removes the fair queueing, but im just interested in efficency.

This is my question, thread the clients? or just use zmq 1-n?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Your question seems to be better asked at [SE Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood ZMQ is making use of things like select(), epoll(), and so forth. Those background threads run the zmqtp protocol, which is what is used to transport your messages, implement the patterns, etc. Your program interacts with those threads using zmq_send(), zmq_recv(), and indeed also zmq_poll(), which itself uses select(). So AFAIK it is all quite efficient, everything blocks when there's nothing happening, and there's nothing really to be gained by multithreading it all yourself.

This is the reason why the IPC transport doesn't work on Windows. There's no select() for pipes on Windows, whereas on *nix pipes, sockets, files, etc. are all just file descriptors and select() works for them all.

This feature of Windows was a major PITA for things like Cygwin; they implemented POSIX's select() on Windows by starting up a thread per non-socket file descriptor and polling the named pipes, serial ports, etc. So under Cygwin you can create pipes and include them in a call to select(), but consequently there's a bunch of threads polling the underlying Windows pipes, which is inefficient. The ZMQ authors chose not to do this.

You would only need to do 2) or 3) if the time taken to service each client in 1) is longer than the time it takes to transfer messages from client to server. Remember that underneath all this is your Ethernet NIC, everything is going through that anyway. Having more threads on the server won't make the Ethernet any quicker.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I understand im limited to my eithernet. Im running high bandwidth 10Gb connections between server and clients and will be nearly maxing the throughput sending as much data as i humanly can. All clients will be trying to talk at the same time and offload their data. This is why im interested in efficiency. Without threading it, it will read the clients one at a time. Will multithreading them read them in parrellel. Thats my issue. I want them to be read out together and not queued. Speed is the priority.

Comment: Sounds like you're heading to the Load Balancing Pattern http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Load-Balancing-Pattern. In this you have a broker in the middle, and you add something to the messages you're sending to allow the broker to associate forward and reverse messages with clients / servers. You can adapt it to use push pull. The broker acts as a single point of contact for the clients, and routes messages on to a number of servers, choosing servers as appropriate.

Comment: thanks, the guide has been good readding for a long time than that. Its actually vastly more complicated than that, (the question was simplified for SO general quiry). Its more like a paranoid pirate mix with distributed computation with client server inputs..... yeh its complicated..... Iv actually moved away form intermediary brokers which was my first port of call, they arent scalable. A system with thousands of computers would ahve a single broker /point of failure and the data rates through the single node will be too much. I had an implimentation with a second backup broker.

Comment: However iv settled on a broker asisted paradigm where by the broker passes connection details of the back end worker nodes to the front end data input machines, so data can flow directly from input to worker, which gets rid of the bottle neck. the broker however keeps track of the the job and the result for relaying the result to other nodes. It also therefore can handle fault tolerance by controllign the front end nodes to resubmit data to other backend nodes in case failure occurs, so it self corrects errors.

Comment: But your left with the same issue a worker node has to receive simulatinous data for a certian time slice from all data input nodes (worker jobs are distributed via time slice). so needed to know if threading them rather than just using a queued 1-n is better. I realise thats probably too much information. So ill ask a simple question using the zmqtp protocoll can multiple messages on a single socket with n connection received in parallel? (hence worth threadding). Or are they fundementally queued? (in which chase threadding wont help). Underneith its got to be multiple tcp connections right?

Comment: AFAIK zmqtp is using epoll() or select() internally, so it is perfectly capable of waiting for multiple connections at once. But fundamentally it's all passing via Ethernet (if they're networked clients). So whilst the internal threads (you can control how many there are with some configuration parameters somewhere) in ZMQ are perhaps reading multiple connections simultaneously, it's all coming through just the one Ethernet NIC. This means that everything is queued at the very lowest layer of the network stack. I can't see even 10G eth overwhelming the ZMQ context's threads.